# Issue while setting up spring annotation based transactions

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc

I have an application which used mix of JPA and JDBC. I have successfully done setup for JPA transaction using @Transactional annotation, but I am not able to make it work for JDBC.

My configuration looks like:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close" id="dataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="url" value="${database.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${database.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${database.password}"/>
        <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true"/>
        <property name="testOnReturn" value="true"/>
        <property name="testWhileIdle" value="true"/>
        <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="1800000"/>
        <property name="numTestsPerEvictionRun" value="3"/>
        <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate" id="jdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
```

My code is :

```
    @Test
        @Transactional
        public void testUpdateSQLwithParam() {
            Object[] params = { "John","", "trol", "test", "M", "Place", "123456789",
            "tom@domain.com" };
             customQueryDao.insert("PERSON_INSERT_QUERY", params);
            String sqlConstant = "PERSON_MASTER_UPADTE_QUERY";
            params = new Object[]{ "Test", 8 };
            customQueryDao.updateSQLwithParam(sqlConstant, params);

}
```

My JDBC code uses jdbcTemplate to execute queries. Please let me know how I can have JDBC transactions using @Transactional annotation. using jpatransactionmgr

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 beans defined with the same id (transactionManager).  Try it with a different ID, maybe like:

```
<bean id="jPATransactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" >
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="dataSourceTransactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

This should work, you can also enable debugging on log4j to see transactions in your log files, here's what I have in my log4j.xml:

```
<!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <level value="debug" />
    </logger>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see from you edit that you tried to fix the problem of multiple transaction manager. But I think you did not remove the good one ... From javadoc of `JpaTransactionManager` : *This transaction manager also supports direct DataSource access within a transaction (i.e. plain JDBC code working with the same DataSource)*.

IMHO you should instead keep the `JpaTransactionManager`, and remove the `DataSourceTransactionManager`. (I have some code using plain JDBC mixed with Hibernate access with a single `HibernateTransactionManager` and transaction are correctly managed ...)

Comment: I am using jdbc template, should JpaTransactionManager is also support this, i have tried it but not working

Comment: @PrashantShah It should work... If there are errors, could you show the stacktrace, or describe what happens ?

Comment: Hi serge, thanks for reply , i am testing below code which is inserting a row and updating other row where 2nd query is giving exception still the first row get inserted in the table